# Undefined reference with OpenSSL

Tags: c++, openssl, bazel

Hello I am trying to link against openssl.

This is the compiler: gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

I am passing -lssl and -lcrypto to the linker as well.

However, I am getting the below error.

```
external/openssl/libssl.a(libssl-lib-ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_store: error: undefined reference to 'X509_LOOKUP_store'
external/openssl/libssl.a(libssl-lib-ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function ssl_validate_ct: error: undefined reference to 'CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_new_ex'
external/openssl/libssl.a(libssl-lib-ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths: error: undefined reference to 'X509_STORE_set_default_paths_ex'
external/openssl/libssl.a(libssl-lib-ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function SSL_CTX_load_verify_file: error: undefined reference to 'X509_STORE_load_file_ex'
external/openssl/libssl.a(libssl-lib-ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function SSL_CTX_load_verify_dir: error: undefined reference to 'X509_STORE_load_path'
external/openssl/libssl.a(libssl-lib-ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:function SSL_CTX_load_verify_store: error: undefined reference to 'X509_STORE_load_store_ex'
external/openssl/libssl.a(libssl-lib-tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c:function SSL_srp_server_param_with_username: error: undefined reference to 'SRP_Calc_B_ex'
external/openssl/libssl.a(libssl-lib-tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c:function SSL_set_srp_server_param_pw: error: undefined reference to 'SRP_create_verifier_BN_ex'
external/openssl/libssl.a(libssl-lib-tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c:function srp_generate_server_master_secret: error: undefined reference to 'SRP_Calc_u_ex'
external/openssl/libssl.a(libssl-lib-tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c:function srp_generate_client_master_secret: error: undefined reference to 'SRP_Calc_u_ex'
external/openssl/libssl.a(libssl-lib-tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c:function srp_generate_client_master_secret: error: undefined reference to 'SRP_Calc_x_ex'
external/openssl/libssl.a(libssl-lib-tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c:function srp_generate_client_master_secret: error: undefined reference to 'SRP_Calc_client_key_ex'
external/openssl/libssl.a(libssl-lib-ssl_conf.o):ssl_conf.c:function cmd_ChainCAPath: error: undefined reference to 'X509_STORE_load_path'
external/openssl/libssl.a(libssl-lib-ssl_conf.o):ssl_conf.c:function cmd_VerifyCAFile: error: undefined reference to 'X509_STORE_load_file_ex'
external/openssl/libssl.a(libssl-lib-ssl_conf.o):ssl_conf.c:function cmd_VerifyCAPath: error: undefined reference to 'X509_STORE_load_path'
external/openssl/libssl.a(libssl-lib-ssl_conf.o):ssl_conf.c:function cmd_ChainCAStore: error: undefined reference to 'X509_STORE_load_store_ex'
external/openssl/libssl.a(libssl-lib-ssl_conf.o):ssl_conf.c:function cmd_VerifyCAStore: error: undefined reference to 'X509_STORE_load_store_ex'
external/openssl/libssl.a(libssl-lib-ssl_conf.o):ssl_conf.c:function cmd_ChainCAFile: error: undefined reference to 'X509_STORE_load_file_ex'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I just had to download the latest stable branch and build from source :)